# Django admin search: how to allow OR operator between search terms?

Tags: django, search, full-text-search, django-admin

django-sphinx seems to be a bit of an overkill.

What's the simplest way to add such functionality?

Thanks

Comment: So when someone searches on this "here is something" are you wanting your query to be "...where x like '%here%' or x like '%is%' or x like '%something%'"?

Comment: No, I mean that a query "here OR is OR something" would turn into that...

Answer (score 3):

This has changed for Django 1.8 (or possibly sooner). Here's what worked for me:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        """
        Returns a tuple containing a queryset to implement the search,
        and a boolean indicating if the results may contain duplicates.
        """
        # Apply keyword searches.
        def construct_search(field_name):
            if field_name.startswith('^'):
                return "%s__istartswith" % field_name[1:]
            elif field_name.startswith('='):
                return "%s__iexact" % field_name[1:]
            elif field_name.startswith('@'):
                return "%s__search" % field_name[1:]
            else:
                return "%s__icontains" % field_name

        use_distinct = False
        search_fields = self.get_search_fields(request)

        # starts here
        filters = models.Q()

        if search_fields and search_term:
            orm_lookups = [construct_search(str(search_field))
                           for search_field in search_fields]
            for bit in search_term.split():
                or_queries = [models.Q(**{orm_lookup: bit})
                              for orm_lookup in orm_lookups]

                # this | operation of Q()'s is the ticket.
                filters = filters | models.Q(reduce(operator.or_, or_queries))

            if not use_distinct:
                for search_spec in orm_lookups:
                    if admin.utils.lookup_needs_distinct(self.opts, search_spec):
                        use_distinct = True
                        break

        # finally
        queryset = queryset.filter(filters)

        return queryset, use_distinct
```

Comment: The last bit of your code seems to be duplicated after the `break` statements. For Python3 I needed also to add `from functools import reduce`, since it was moved there. Otherwise it seems to work great!

Comment: Ah, I've cleaned up those extra statements — thanks Jarno!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more complete snippet:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList
from django.db import models
import operator

class MyChangeList(ChangeList):
    def __init__(self, *a):
        super(MyChangeList, self).__init__(*a)
    def get_query_set(self, request):
        # First, we collect all the declared list filters.
        (self.filter_specs, self.has_filters, remaining_lookup_params,
         use_distinct) = self.get_filters(request)

        # Then, we let every list filter modify the queryset to its liking.
        qs = self.root_query_set
        for filter_spec in self.filter_specs:
            new_qs = filter_spec.queryset(request, qs)
            if new_qs is not None:
                qs = new_qs

        try:
            # Finally, we apply the remaining lookup parameters from the query
            # string (i.e. those that haven't already been processed by the
            # filters).
            qs = qs.filter(**remaining_lookup_params)
        except (SuspiciousOperation, ImproperlyConfigured):
            # Allow certain types of errors to be re-raised as-is so that the
            # caller can treat them in a special way.
            raise
        except Exception, e:
            # Every other error is caught with a naked except, because we don't
            # have any other way of validating lookup parameters. They might be
            # invalid if the keyword arguments are incorrect, or if the values
            # are not in the correct type, so we might get FieldError,
            # ValueError, ValidationError, or ?.
            raise IncorrectLookupParameters(e)

        # Use select_related() if one of the list_display options is a field
        # with a relationship and the provided queryset doesn't already have
        # select_related defined.
        if not qs.query.select_related:
            if self.list_select_related:
                qs = qs.select_related()
            else:
                for field_name in self.list_display:
                    try:
                        field = self.lookup_opts.get_field(field_name)
                    except models.FieldDoesNotExist:
                        pass
                    else:
                        if isinstance(field.rel, models.ManyToOneRel):
                            qs = qs.select_related()
                            break

        # Set ordering.
        ordering = self.get_ordering(request, qs)
        qs = qs.order_by(*ordering)

        # Apply keyword searches.
        def construct_search(field_name):
            if field_name.startswith('^'):
                return "%s__istartswith" % field_name[1:]
            elif field_name.startswith('='):
                return "%s__iexact" % field_name[1:]
            elif field_name.startswith('@'):
                return "%s__search" % field_name[1:]
            else:
                return "%s__icontains" % field_name

        if self.search_fields and self.query:
            orm_lookups = [construct_search(str(search_field))
                           for search_field in self.search_fields]
            or_queries = []
            for bit in self.query.split():
                or_queries += [models.Q(**{orm_lookup: bit})
                              for orm_lookup in orm_lookups]
            if len(or_queries) > 0:
                qs = qs.filter(reduce(operator.or_, or_queries))
            if not use_distinct:
                for search_spec in orm_lookups:
                    if lookup_needs_distinct(self.lookup_opts, search_spec):
                        use_distinct = True
                        break

        if use_distinct:
            return qs.distinct()
        else:
            return qs
```

and in your ModelAdmin

```
def get_changelist(*a, **k):
    return MyChangeList
```

Comment: You should use a real user name and update your profile, then your contributions will be taken more seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Here's where you might start:

1. Subclass the `django.contrib.admin.views.main.ChangeList` admin view class, overriding the `get_query_set` method to return a query set that takes the 'OR' keyword into account.
2. Tell your ModelAdmin class to use your new `ChangeList` subclass:

In your `admin.py` file:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.main import ChangeList

class YourChangeList(ChangeList)
    def get_query_set(self):
        # I'll leave this part to you...

class YourAdminClass(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def __init__(self):
        super(YourAdminClass, self).__init__()
        self.changelist_view = YourChangeListClass
```